# How to compile a Delphi 7 project group file (.bpg) using the command line?

Tags: delphi, build, continuous-integration, delphi-7

I've grouped a lot of projects in a project group. All the info is in the project.bpg. Now I'd like to automatically build them all.

How do I build all the projects using the command line?

I'm still using Delphi 7.

Comment: We use a script to loop through the entries for a groupproj and fire up the command line compiler for each project encountered. Not making this an answer, because the script I have available is for groupproj's and you are using bpg's. If you are interested, I'll try to find the bpg version. No guarantees, as I will have to dig around at work in releases of 6+ years back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I never tried it myself, but [here](http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/delphi_make/deutsch.html) is a German article describing that you can use `make -f ProjectGroup.bpg` because `*.bpg`s essentially are makefiles.

Comment: Here is the command using Delphi own Make: "c:\Arquivos de programas
\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\make.exe" -B  -fproject-group.bpg. Unfortunately it is useless since the make don't use the relative paths inside each file. I've found this thread today: http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-pascal-delphi-misc/134632-build-project-group-command-line.html

Comment: Sorry about that. Reading stuff like that makes me glad we are on D2007 so we can use MSBuild. With it, it's really easy to build from the command line. Maybe you can upgrade to D2007? Or have a look at FinalBuilder. It [seems to be able to handle bpg's](http://www.finalbuilder.com/forum.aspx?aft=9491).

Answer (score 1):

You can also run Delphi from the command line or a batch file, passing the .bpg file name as a parameter.

Edit: Example (for D2007, but can be adjusted for D7):

=== rebuild.cmd (excerpt) ===

```
@echo off
set DelphiPath=C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin
set DelphiExe=bds.exe
set LibPath=V:\Library
set LibBpg=Library.groupproj
set LibErr=Library.err
set RegSubkey=BDSClean

:buildlib
echo Rebuilding %LibBpg%...
if exist "%LibPath%\%LibErr%" del /q "%LibPath%\%LibErr%"
"%DelphiPath%\%DelphiExe%" -pDelphi -r%RegSubkey% -b "%LibPath%\%LibBpg%"
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto buildlibok
```

Comment: would you send an exemple? I've tried before asking and didn't manage to do it.

Comment: With Delphi do you mean the IDE? I have not been able to pass a bpg to the command line compiler as @neves is asking...

Comment: Is it really a great idea to fire up an IDE for this? Surely the command line compiler dcc32 is what you want.

Comment: @David: I think that's left for the user to decide; the possibility simply is there.

Comment: I should point out the -r switch which specifies an alternate registry key. This can be clear of all design packages (empty "Known Packages" subkey) which prevents potential conflicts when rebuilding packages normally installed in the IDE. It also makes the IDE start up fast.

Answer (score 0):

As I said as a comment to Ulrich Gerhardt answer, the make project_group.bpg is useless if your projects are in subdirectories. Make won't use relative paths and the projects won't compile correctly.

I've made a python script to compile all the DPRs in every subdirectory. This is what I really wanted to do, but I'll leave the above answer as marked. Although it didn't worked for me, It really answered my question.

Here is my script to compile_all.py . I believe it may help somebody:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os.path
import subprocess
import sys

#put this file in your root dir
BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 
os.chdir(BASE_PATH)

os.environ['PATH'] += "C:\\Program Files\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Bin" #your delphi compiler path
DELPHI = "DCC32.exe"  
DELPHI_PARAMS = ['-B', '-Q', '-$D+', '-$L+']


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(BASE_PATH):
    projects = [project for project in files if project.lower().endswith('.dpr')]
    if ('FastMM' in root ): #put here projects you don't want to compile
        continue
    os.chdir(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, root))
    for project in projects:
        print
        print '*** Compiling:', os.path.join(root, project)
        result = subprocess.call([DELPHI] + DELPHI_PARAMS + [project])
        if result != 0:
            print 'Failed for', project, result
            sys.exit(result)
```

Another vantage of this approach is that you don't need to add new projects to your bpg file. If it is in a subdir, it will compile.